# Nestet Microdata structure with Schema.org

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

Can you please tell me if this structure is correct?

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
   <div itemprop="creator">
      <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
           <a itemprop="URL" itemprop="name"><a/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

- Is this structure correctly nested?
- Does `itemprop="name"` belong to `itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"`?
- Can I use two or more `itemprop` in one element?

Comment: user3307827, I rolled-back your edit. Please don’t introduce additional questions that are not directly related to your initial code. If you have a question about other code, you should create another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `itemprop="creator"` must be [on the same element as the `itemscope`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884018/1591669).
- `itemprop="name"` [should not be specified on `a`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/58944/17633). If you have it on `a`, [the URL (in `href`) would be the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283706/1591669). As a solution, you could add a `span` (as child or as parent of `a`).
- The property name is `url`, not `URL`.
- Your closing `a` tag has to be `</a>`, not `<a/>`.
- The `creator` property links to a Person or Organization, not an Article. So either you meant that, or you should use a different property. Maybe you mean [`about`](http://schema.org/about)?

So this would give you:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

  <div itemprop="creator" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <a itemprop="url"href="…"><span itemprop="name">…</span></a>
  </div>

  <!-- and/or -->

  <div itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <a itemprop="url" href="…"><span itemprop="name">…</span></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

> Dose `itemprop="name"` belong to `itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"`?

Yes, always to its nearest parent `itemscope`.

> Can I use two or more `itemprop` in one element?

No, you can’t add several `itemprop` attributes on the same element. But you can [have several properties in one `itemprop` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216506/1591669).

However, make sure that all the properties expect the same value. This is not the case with Schema.org’s `name` (expects *Text*) and `url` (expects *URL*). If specified on `a`, the value will be the value of the `href` attribute, not the value of the `a` element.

Comment: I use an alternative way to use URL and Name...Do you think it is true  or I must use URL in <a> tag?

Comment: @user3307827: See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283292/nestet-microdata-structure-with-schema-org#comment33853159_22283292) to your question: Please don’t add additional questions that aren’t directly related to your initial code.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your great help :)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
<a itemprop="URL" itemprop="name"><a/><br />
```

should be

```
<a itemprop="URL" itemprop="name"></a>
```

Read [Extending HTML5 — Microdata](http://html5doctor.com/microdata/)